# System.NullReferenceException with select clause

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-2, nullreferenceexception

Hello beloved Community :D

right now i'm working on my first big project and am a little bit stuck.
I'm trying to validate some input.

Therefore i'm using this function:

```
public static Validatable<string> RequiredOr(this Validatable<string> that, Func<Validatable<string>, bool> func)
{
    return that.DoEvaluate && !(func(that) || that.Value != null)
            ? that.Error(ML.Get("Validation", "IsRequired"))
            : that;
}
```

For normal validation i'm using this:

```
public Validatable<TProperty> Validate<TProperty>(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> expr)
    {
        return new Validatable<TProperty>(
            new ErrorTrackerWrapper(ErrorTracker, expr.Body), expr.Compile()(Value));
    }
```

And this part to call the "RequiredOr" Function:

```
var header = from name in v.Validate(it => it.Name).Required().MaxLength(Constants.String.NameLength)
                     from startDate in v.Validate(it => it.StartDate).Required().After(DateTime.Today)
                     from endDate in v.Validate(it => it.EndDate).Required().After(DateTime.Today)
                     from endTime in v.Validate(it => it.EndTime).BlockErrors().Required().ReplaceIfInvalid(new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 23, 30, 0))
                     from requestedCurrency in v.Validate(it => it.RequestedCurrency).Required()
                     from language1 in v.Validate(it => it.Language1).Required()
                     from language2 in v.Validate(it => it.Language2)
                     from language3 in v.Validate(it => it.Language3)
                     from hasMoreInformation in v.Validate(it => it.HasMoreInformation)
                     // TODOJP: If "hasMoreInformation" is true, then "moreInformationEmail" has to be required.
                     from moreInformationEmail in v.Validate(it => it.MoreInformationEmail).IsEmail()//.RequiredOr(p => !hasMoreInformation)
                     from isAnonymous in v.Validate(it => it.IsAnonymous)
                     select new AnnouncementHeader(
                        currentUser,
                        type,
                        name,
                        startDate,
                        endDate.SetTime(new Time(endTime.Hour, endTime.Minute)),
                        isAnonymous,
                        infoField,
                        requestedCurrency,
                        language1,
                        language2,
                        language3,
                        hasMoreInformation,
                        moreInformationEmail);
```

So far this is correct, but some how, it keeps telling me "hasMoreInformation" in the "RequiredOr" part is a NullReferenceException.

I was able to trace the error back up to the "RequiredOr" Function.

I would like to check if "HasMoreInformation" is true or not and then set the field as "Required" or not.

I hope you guy's understand what i'm trying to tell you.
And thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Please post the code of Validate(), and also please post the entire linq query. It's difficult to guess at what's going on as it is.  The title says there's a problem with the select clause, but you haven't included the select clause.

Comment: I updated the codes.
The Error is not in the select clause - sorry for that - it's in the "RequiredOr" part of "moreInformationEmail". (look at the commented part)

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused.  Does `Validate()` return an IEnumerable?  Or does it return some other type that's amenable to query comprehension syntax?

Comment: `Validate()` returns an `Validatable<TProperty>`.
I was able to trace the error back to the "RequiredOr" function.

Comment: Is Validatable<TProperty> enumerable?  Or does it declare its own `Select` and `SelectMany` methods?

Answer (score 0):

With a potentially null object, you have to test whether or not the field exists prior to testing whether or not it is true. The consequence of breaking the rule is a null ref exception. That is how it works.

If the item is nullable, there is always a potential it will be null. You can make it not so if you default the value, but then the default has to have a single meaning and not mean both "it could be default" and "it could be explicitly set by the user".

If a default makes no sense, then you assume a null object, prior to validation, either indicates valid or not.

Since I have very little context, I would recommend writing this out in long form to solve the problem. You can then rethink in a deferred execution style (LINQ). I say this because you seem to want to pick only valid, when the item is not null AND something else that is not explicitly stated (based on the comment about checking required after). Walk through the problem before you LINQ it up.

NEW: Still sticking to last line about solving before LINQ-ing up the solution (and I will include all forms of deferred execution here, not just LINQ).

Without me actually spending a lot of time on the statement, you have some LINQ and some extension methods (fluid syntax with chained methods, blah, blah). All of this is deferred execution. If you were to pull down symbols and pop through the stack, you might find that the order of deferred execution is part of the issue. it is often the only way to debug the steaming pile of abstractions. (Yes, I have seen a 47 line nested LINQ statement with function pointers and extension methods)

When you use the fluid programming style, you are essentially running a pseudo IoC type of pattern, as the method farthest to the right gets past to the next method until you get all the way to the left. Very bad analogy-like explanation, so I will likely be corrected, but you are working with function pointers to keep the flow in the correct method. Example:

Colonel.Sanders.Loves.Chicken("fried");

Function pointers, extension methods and RX, oh my! Pretty neat stuff from the philosophical standpoint, but prone to bad juju if you don't really understand how this works. It often makes for very clear syntax, but creates a debug nightmare.

If you further stick in a LINQ statement to choose meal plans or fast food restaurants, you end up with a lot of deferred goo coming from different directions. And, if one bit is not in the correct order, some code runs prior to a necessary precursor. Since LINQ and extension methods use a different methodology, mixing them increases the chance of having bits run in the incorrect order. And debugging with symbols is often the only way to hack through, as the entire blob of deferred abstractions gets "compiled" at runtime.

So, to end this long post, you need to either a) debug through and figure out why you are getting the null ref (most likely some misordering of calls in your stack of deferred execution) or b) solve the problem first using non-deferred methodologies (or perhaps running one bit of deferred goo at a time?).

Comment: The Item is not nullable - it can only be true or false and default is false

Comment: What it appears is you are trying to accomplish both the validation for the set and then shaping data in a single call. On top of that, you are using different means of deferring execution by chaining LINQ constructs with extension methods piled in. Added rest to answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I think that's what i needed to.
Like i wrote (edited) in my post, i was able to debug it to the `RequireOr()` function and noticed that it's a problem with the `func(that)`.

Comment: Deferred execution is a royal pain. It is really nice syntax and syntactical sugar, but the heavy abstraction hides so much. You can debug with symbols and start to see ordering, but the more than is cobbled together, the harder it gets.